# Configure port for BlazeDS

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, blazeds

I'm new to BlazeDS. I've downloaded BlazeDS 4 and installed in on my Tomcat server. How can I make it to listen to port distinct from 8080? I change port in channels configuration in `services-config.xml`, and my client application sends requests for new port, but they fail. How can I make server listen to custom port? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BlazeDS runs within the container (Tomcat), it will listen on the same ports as the web application it is running within.

I do not believe there is a way around this. If you are using apache as a proxy, all the blaze connections should work normally through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any hard coded port in services-config.xml. Instead, keep the initial way (like that:

```
<endpoint url="https://{server.name}:{server.port}........
```

If you are using the Tomcat server from your BlazeDS turnkey installation go to blazeds-folder/tomcat/conf/, locate server.xml file and replace 8400 with 8080. Restart the server.

If not, take a look on the same file on your Tomcat folder, that's the file where the connectors are configured.